# Array contains multiple last values

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I'm recently having an issue with adding values to an array.
The array contains only multiple last values added.
I was looking on Stack Overflow but all answers said either that a static field is used or there is the same object. But none of these are my case.

Here's my code:

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo[] FooColection = new Foo[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Foo Bar = new Foo(i);//making a new Object everytime
            FooColection[i] = Bar;
            for (int j = 0; j < i;j++ ) {
                System.out.println(FooColection[i].getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Foo class:

```
public class Foo {

    private int value;//non-static field

    public Foo(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void change(int newVal) {
        this.value = newVal;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is because of your nested loop, nothing else. Consider removing the nested loop and just print as you iterate.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I should have Noticed that I used `i` instead of `j`. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Glad it helped! ^^.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing objects that many times. It is in `j` loop and you're printing with respect to `i`

`System.out.println(FooColection[i].getValue());`

You should remove that `j` loop as your `Foo` is not a collection, it's a single object.

Comment: I didn't notice I'm printing with respect to `i` I should Have been printing with respect to `j`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your array. Just remove the `j` loop and you're good.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo[] FooColection = new Foo[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Foo Bar = new Foo(i);//making a new Object everytime
            FooColection[i] = Bar;
            System.out.println(FooColection[i].getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I used the Nested loop to write out the whole array and I didn't notice I didn't use `j` as intended

Comment: @IQuick143 It shouldn't be nested at all, unless you want to print what you just did. :)